# Throttle number of inflight messages in Amazon SQS queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I know that Amazon SQS has its own internal maximum number of inflight messages. But is there a way to set that number yourself to be smaller? For example, let's say I don't want more than 10 messages being processed at any time.

What are some ways in which that could be achieved? I believe an approach similar to `shovelling`, in RabbitMQ. I could have 2 queues, `A` & `B`. All messages would be first sent to `A`. Then if there are less than 10 inflight messages in `B` the message would be sent to `B`. Consumers would then consume from `B`.

Then I have to solve the problem of when to transfer messages from `A` to `B`. Ideally this would a be serverless solution. I had a couple of ideas such as:

1. **CloudWatch Events** - Using CloudWatch I could trigger a Lambda Function (lets call it `ShoveLambda`) to move messages across given that there is processing room in `B`. But the shortest polling time would be 60 seconds the min interval set by CloudWatch.
2. **SNS Topic**
   As well as doing **1**, I could also have a SNS topic which upon a new publish, would trigger `ShoveLambda` to move messages. When a message in `B` is processed, the consumer would also publish a Notification to SNS, which would trigger `ShoveLambda`, (I could also have the consumer call a `ShoveLambda` directly, thoughts?). This would mean in the worst case there would be a 60 second delay between a message being shovelled from `A` to `B`, but most of the time, there would be a regular amount of shovels anyway because of messages being processed in `B`.

Any thoughts and ideas on this approach would be great. Is this approach good? Should I limit the number of concurrent `ShoveLambda` executions to 1? As if 2 executions execute at the same time I will shovel double what I want, and even I limit the executions, I imagine there could be still concurrency problems, but I'm not too concerned if too many messages are shovelled to `B` so long as its within 30% of the desired maximum inflight messages or some upper bound.

But as I write this I worry that there are holes in this approach.

**More Info**
There are a few use cases we potentially have for doing this, such as restricting a customer to only running 10 jobs at a time. But allowing the servers to scale independently. To perform different types of processing.

But our main case is we have a work flow to process files, and one stage in that workflow involves a monolithic windows server application which we can’t scale. We interact via SOAP API requests. It itself queues jobs in a way, with its SQL database it runs as part of the app.

It is a bottleneck in our flow, but we don’t want it to bank up 100s of Jobs. We have containers which process other parts of the pipeline and also interact with this SOAP API. They should scale out based on the files coming in, but we don’t want the number of jobs on the Windows box to go beyond let’s say 10 at a time.

I hope that gives enough context.

Comment: Which service you are using is it SQS? Standard or FIFO?

Comment: What you can do is you can GET the total number of inflight messages in SQS before adding new message to the queue. As per your requirement if there are less than 10 messages in the queue you can add messages till the count reaches 10. In that way you can always maintain 10 in-flight messages without compromising performance and with a simple API call.

Comment: Can you please tell us _why_ you want to limit inflight messages? This is normally a function of the workers that process the messages. If you want less inflight, then simply run less workers. Please tell us more about your situation, so that we can provide a better answer.

Comment: As requested, more info @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to limit the number of inflight messages, then simply don't grab more off the queue. When you want more inflight, then grab more messages from the queue. If you want to limit the number of messages being processed, your app should apply that logic *before* grabbing messages.

If, however, you have an AWS Lambda function configured to process messages from the SQS queue, you can set a **concurrency limit** on the Lambda function to limit the number of simultaneous executions.

See: [Reserving Concurrency for a Lambda Function - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/per-function-concurrency.html)

If you are spending a lot of time waiting for an external service before being able to process messages, then it is likely that AWS Lambda is not a good choice for the architecture. This is because you pay for the Lambda function, even while it is simply waiting for the external service.